# How would you delete a random key from a dictionary, but ONLY if the item has a certain value?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm looking about simulating the Monty Hall problem, and to be totally honest I haven't gotten so far. My code looks like this:

```
import random
doors = {"a":"false", "b":"false", "c":"false"}   
doors[random.choice(list(doors.keys()))] = "true" 
del doors[random.choice(list(doors.values()))]    
print(doors)
```

My issue right now is how on line four, I'm trying to delete a random door that has the value 'false'. My issue is that I don't know how to specify that I only want to randomly select out of a list with the value 'false'.

Any ideas? I've looked around a fair bit but I couldn't find a solution. This is my first post so sorry if I messed up somewhere!

(I am using a version of Python 3, not 2)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension

```
del doors[random.choice([k for k,v in doors.items() if v == 'false'])]
```